# updating document inside array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to update my answer object inside answers array. I am using following schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    postedBy: {
      type: ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "User",
    },
    question: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    photo: {
      data: String,
      required: false,
    },
    answers: [
      {
        userId: { type: ObjectId, ref: "User" },
        answer: String,
      },
    ],
    questionType: {
      data: String,
      required: false,
    },
  },

  { timeStamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Question", questionSchema);
```

I am using updateOne method to update my answer in my db. Can anyone explain what is missing here. I am been trying to solve this since hours

```
exports.updateAnswer = (req, res) => {
  const questionId = req.body.questionId;
  const answerId = req.body.answerId;

  Question.findOne({ _id: questionId }).exec((err, question) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: errorHandler(err),
      });
      return;
    }
    if (!question) {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: "question not found",
      });
      return;
    }
  });

  Question.updateOne(
    { _id: answerId },
    {
      $set: {
        "answers.$.answer": "This is update answer. My name is Ravi Dubey",
      },
    },
    { new: true },
    (err, success) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
          error: errorHandler(err),
        });
      }
      res.json({
        msg: "answer updated successfully",
        success,
      });
    }
  );
};
```

My result is coming successful but answer is not updating in db.
I am confused on Question.updateOne method.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: When updating an array, one of the array fields should be a included as part of the query. So since you have only `{ _id: answerId }` in the update query it will through an error. If you are getting a success response then I think there is no record in the `Question` collection that matches the provided id (answerId)

Comment: Question.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: questionId }),
    ({ _id: answerId },...

I tried this way but once I hit the API, i get no error neither the i get any success msg.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to query based on `id` of one of the documents in the `answers` array then instead of `{_id: answerId}` you need to provide `{'answers._id': answerId}`. And also if you need the updated document as result then you should use the `findOneAndUpdate` method.

```js
Question.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "answers._id": answerId },
  { $set: { "answers.$.answer": "some answer" } },
  { new: true },
  (err, data) => {
    // handle response
  }
);
```